# jquery insertAfter into collection (not in DOM)

Tags: jquery

In this example I need to add into `elements` variable the element `#B` from `#source2` container but after the element `#A` and not work.

However in the second example below, if I insert first the `#B` element to `source1` container that work ok but I don't need to append `#B` into source1 container and also I would like to avoid that every time to re-append #B element into #source2 (or clone -> append -> remove)

**The question is:**
How to insertAfter directly into collection variable not in DOM?

```js
//EXAMPLE 1
var elements = $('#source1').children();

var cloned = $('#B').clone(true,true);

cloned.insertAfter(elements.find('#A'));

console.log('example1',elements.length); //show #A and #C ... Expected #A,#B,#C

//EXAMPLE 2
//This work but I don't need to append #B into source1 container
$('#B').insertAfter($('#A'));

elements = $('#source1').children();
//here I need every time to re-append #B element into #source2 and I try to avoid that
$('#B').appendTo('#source2');

console.log('example2',elements.length); //show as expected #A,#B,#C
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="source1">
 <div id="A">
  A
 </div>
 <div id="C">
  C
 </div>
</div>
<div id="source2">
 <div id="B">
  B
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with collection variable? And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In jquery multiple elements selected is called `a collection`.
Is very complicated (and very extended) to explain here the entire logic of my app. Simply I need to add into `elements` variable (that is the collection variable) another element but after one specific not at end. This is strange for me because for example: `cloned.appendTo(elements)` that work but add `cloned` to the end of `elements` ... so `appendTo()` work but `insertAfter()` not work

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved it by clone entire container `source1` to `elements` variable

I have changed

`var elements = $('#source1').children();`

with

`var elements = $('#source1').clone();`

```js
    var elements = $('#source1').clone();

    var cloned = $('#B').clone();

    cloned.insertAfter(elements.find('#A'));

    //Now I can select all childrens  #A,#B,#C
    elements = elements.children();

    console.log(elements.length); // = 3 and show as Expected #A,#B,#C
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="source1">
 <div id="A">
  A
 </div>
 <div id="C">
  C
 </div>
</div>
<div id="source2">
 <div id="B">
  B
 </div>
</div>
```